# execute periodic network requests in batch

Tags: android, android-source

I would like to know about the behavior of android in case of periodic network requests. As of Android Kitkat documentation "Android works with the device hardware to collect and deliver sensor events efficiently in batches, rather than individually as they are detected. This lets the device's application processor remain in a low-power idle state until batches are delivered". This functionality was introduced in android 4.4. 
AlarmManager redefined in Kitkat "To improve power efficiency, Android now batches together alarms from all apps that occur at reasonably similar times so the system wakes the device once instead of several times to handle each alarm".

So my question is that, is there any way to do the same in case of network calls or any API available which provides the same functionality.

Comment: Have you tried IntentService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found that, there is no simple API available for batch network calls but there is a way to achieve the goal is to use the Google's recommendations about regular updates.
As per documentation "*When scheduling updates, use inexact repeating alarms that allow the system to "phase shift" the exact moment each alarm triggers*".

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates.html#OptimizedPolling)